# ngRoute not working at all in IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I am having a problem with AngularJS (more like the routing) and any version of IE. It comes to the point where Chrome, Firefox and Safari work fine, without a pinch of problems. But when I start to work with IE ... everything goes wrong.

Normally when I navigate to the URL of localhost, it start with "localhost:52201" and changes to "localhost:55201/#/ExpenseOverview" which is indeed the first 'page/view' that is loaded, according to my AngularApp (code below)

---

```
var angularApp = angular.module('AngularApp', ['ngRoute']);
    angularApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/ExpenseOverview', {
                controller: 'ExpenseOverviewController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/ExpenseOverview.aspx'
            })
            .when('/AddExpense/', {
                controller: 'AddExpenseController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/AddExpense.aspx'
            })
            .when("/AddExpense/:update", {
                controller: 'UpdateExpenseController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/AddExpense.aspx'
             })
            .when('/ApproveExpense', {
                controller: 'ExpenseOverviewController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/ExpenseOverview.aspx'
            })
            .when('/TypeGrid', {
                controller: 'TypeGridController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/TypeGrid.aspx'
            })
            .when('/TypeGrid/:updated', {
                controller: 'TypeGridController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/TypeGrid.aspx'
            })
            .when('/AddType', {
                controller: 'AddTypeController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/AddType.aspx'
            })
            .when('/AddType/:update', {
                controller: 'UpdateTypeController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/AddType.aspx'
            })
            .when('/ProjectGrid', {
                controller: 'ProjectGridController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/ProjectGrid.aspx'
            })
            .when('/ProjectGrid/:updated', {
                controller: 'ProjectGridController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/ProjectGrid.aspx'
            })
            .when('/AddProject', {
                controller: 'AddProjectController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/AddProject.aspx'
            })
            .when('/AddProject/:update', {
                controller: 'UpdateProjectController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/AddProject.aspx'
            })
            .when('/Organogram', {
                controller: 'OrganogramController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/Organogram.aspx'
            })

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/ExpenseOverview' });
    }]);
```

---

Just to point this out, I know I am working with .aspx-files instead of static .html-files, but this doesn't matter right now, because it's of no concern to this problem.

As I stated before, this problem only occurs when using IE. It doesn't matter what version I am using, from IE8 to IE11, none of those are doing the routing and showing views.

I have tried multiple solutions, such as adding certain -tags to the head, adding an **id="ng-app"** to my -tag and so on, from which none of them resulted in a view.

Something is unexplainable to me is that when I debug my project with Visual Studio and Internet Explorer, everything works fine, like there was never any problem at all. After I published my website and put it online .. well, it's quite clear what that result is (otherwise I wouldn't be posting this).

I seriously need help with this issue. I need to be able to deploy my website to both PC, iOS, Android and Windows Surface. Every platform-browser but IE works and I cannot find a plausible solution for this.

So I thought someone out there knew the cause, might know a solution or maybe a workaround/fix for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what is happening in IE? Is there any errors in the console?

Comment: The problem has been fixed. It was due to the server, which was emulating the website in IE7 modus, while the default server settings specifically said this wasn't allowed to happen, it still did. Considering Angular doesn't work in IE versions below 8, this was causing the views to not load. It was fixed by forcing the website to not run in IE7 modus.